# React auth with localStorage

Tags: reactjs, authentication, timing

The below code work for logging in but I keep getting an error of undefined at first, I believe it might be the timing of everything, the local storage setItem takes too long, trying to set a delay but am not managing.

```
    async function login(username, password) {
         const response = await axios.post(API_URL + "signin", {
            username,
            password
          });
    
          if (response.data.accessToken && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
         }
          
        return response.data;
 }
```

Comment: why we need this line -> `typeof window !== 'undefined'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was where I was loading username was the local storage wasnt set yet ,so the system responded with undefined ,to fix the proble just set an if statement saying toad the usersDetails when available

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this if it works or not?

```
    async login(username, password) {
        axios.post(API_URL + "signin", {
            username, password
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.accessToken && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
                    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
                }
            })
        return response.data;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the snipped output of response?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-fermat-ybrl7?file=/src/authService.js hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say definitely without seeing the exact error you're receiving, but what jumps out to me as problematic is `response.data.accessToken` because if you try to access the `accessToken` property of `data` when `data` is null or undefined, that will cause an error.

My suggestion is for you to add a check to be sure that `response.data` is truthy before accessing the `accessToken` property. For example,

```
if(response.data && response.data.accessToken && ...) {
```

There are other ways to handle this common issue such as the `get` method of lodash or optional chaining.

Comment: Hi the Error Im having is this (TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null) I think the problem is the setItem is to slow, a timing issue (Dont realy now still new at this)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Could you paste the part of your code related to logging in where you try to access the `name` attribute of an object? (`<object>.name`) That would be very useful to see based on the error you're receiving.

Comment: I added the sighnIn form in sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-fermat-ybrl7?file=/src/loginForm.js

Comment: The error dissapears when I reload the page and goes to the next page ,dont know if this helps